# How to style contenteditable=true when hovered?

Tags: css

I want to change background of elements inside a div, only when hovered and when their property contenteditable is true.

I have tried :

```
#myDiv[contenteditable="true"]:hover  { background-color: rgba(217, 245, 255,0.5);}
```

But it doesn't work. 
And if I move the pseudo class to the div :

```
#myDiv:hover [contenteditable="true"]  { background-color: rgba(217, 245, 255,0.5);}
```

Then all fields with contenteditable=true get the background... any trick to fix that in pure css ?

EDIT : HTML example:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <span contenteditable="true">blabla</span>
    <div "subdiv" contenteditable="true">blibli</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will select all direct children of `.myDiv` with `[contenteditable="true"]`

```css
.myDiv:hover > *[contenteditable="true"] {
  background-color: rgba(217, 245, 255,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <p contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <span contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
  <p contenteditable="false">Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to change the elements inside the div, not the div itself

Comment: thanks! that works... one more question, why .myDiv:hover > * and not .myDiv *:hover ?

Comment: @Vincent Teyssier Updated my answer. This will select everything inside `myDiv` with `contenteditable="true"`

Comment: `>` is for direct children but you can change that.

Answer (score 3):

Make the selector as you had it, then put an * next to it.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style>
    #editor[contenteditable="true"]:hover * {
      border: 3px inset grey;
      width: 400px;
      height: 200;
      margin: 30px;
    }
    #editor .editable:hover {
      background-color: rgba(217, 245, 255, 0.5);
    }
    .circle {
      border-radius: 60px;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="editor" class="editable" contenteditable="true">
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX||||||||||||||||||||
    <br/>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="editable"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```